# Fourier transform of $\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I was given to calculate the Fourier Transform of $\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}$.

So, the problem is to calculate the integral

$$
\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{x}{\sinh(x)}e^{-i \omega x} dx
$$

I know such an integrals can be evaluated using complex analysis, but I don't know how to take the proper contour.

Function under integral has a removable singularity at $x=0$ and poles at $x=\pi i k, 0 \ne k \in \mathbb{Z}$

I've tried this contour:
[image]

But it doesn't work since the $x/\sinh(x)$ is not even bounded on the half-circle, so Jordan Lemma is inapplicable.

And this one:
[image]

But I don't quite see how to integrate over any side of a rectangle.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\,e^{-i\omega x}}{\sinh x}dx=i\frac{d}{d \omega}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-i\omega x}}{\sinh x}dx=i\frac{d}{d \omega}J(\omega)$$
where $J(\omega)$ is understood in the principal value sense. To evaluate $J(\omega)$ let's consider the following contour:

[image]

where we added small half-circles around $z=0$ and $z=\pi i$, and also two paths $[1]$ and $[2]$ - to close the contour. Given that $\,\sinh(z+\pi i)=-\sinh z$, and $\,e^{-i\omega (z+\pi i)}=e^{-i\omega z}e^{\pi \omega}$
$$\oint \frac{e^{-i\omega z}}{\sinh z}dz=J(\omega)+I_{1r}+[1]+J(\omega)e^{\pi \omega}+I_{2r}+[2]$$
where $I_{1,2\,r}$ are the integrals along the half-circles. We can show that integrals $[1,2]$ tend to zero at $R\to\infty$. There are no poles inside the contour, therefore $\displaystyle \oint=0$.
$$J(\omega)(1+e^{\pi\omega})=-I_{1r}-I_{2r}=\pi i\underset{z=0; \,e^{\pi i}}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{e^{-i\omega z}}{\sinh z}=\pi i(1-e^{\pi \omega})$$
$$J(\omega)=-\pi i\tanh \frac{\pi \omega}{2}$$
$$I(\omega)=i\frac{d}{d\omega}J(\omega)=\frac{\pi^2}{2}\frac{1}{\cosh^2\frac{\pi \omega}{2}}$$

Comment: Hey Svyatoslav! Thank you, great answer! I want to add a bit to your answer. In order to show that $[1]$ and $[2]$ converge to $0$ as $R \to \infty$ it's enough to show this evaluation on the denominator: $| \exp(x+iy)-\exp(-x-iy) |=\exp(x) \cdot (\cos(y)+ i\sin(y)) - \exp(-x)(\cos(y)-i\sin(y)|=|(\exp(x)-\exp(-x))cos(y)+i(\exp(x)+\exp(-x))\sin(y)|=(\exp(2x)+\exp(-2x)-2)\cos^2(y)+(\exp(2x)+\exp(-2x)+2)\sin^2(y)=\exp(2x)+\exp(-2x)-2\cos(2y)$ which goes to $\infty$ really fast as $x=\text{const}=R\to \infty$

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Just use the inequality (for example, replace $-2\cos 2y$ by $-2$) - to show that the absolutevalue of the integral is bounded by some function which $\to 0$ at $R\to \infty$.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the question was in regards to showing that the integration over the semicircle $|z|=N+1/2$ vanishes as $N\to \infty$.  This answer merely evaluates the sum of the residues.  Moreover, no justification was given for interchanging the order of differentiation and integration.  Finally, there is no partial derivative involved inasmuch as the integral is a function of $\omega$ only.

Comment: @Mark Viola, thank you for your comment. My apology for the possible inaccuracy - I  am a former applied guy :) Regarding the task formulation - probably, I did not catch correctly, but I got that one of the questions was a possible proper contour - I proposed the one. The partial derivative notation - you are right, just correcting.

Comment: Regarding the derivative under the integral sing: 
$$\Big|\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-i(\omega+h) x}}{\sinh x}dx-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-i\omega x}}{\sinh x}dx-ih\int_0^\infty\frac{xe^{-i\omega x}}{\sinh x}dx\Big|$$
$$<\int_0^\infty\Big|\frac{e^{-i\omega x}}{\sinh x}\Big(e^{ihx}-1-ihx\Big)\Big|dx<\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{(2\sin^2\frac{hx}{2})^2+(\sin hx-hx)^2}}{\sinh x}dx$$
$$<\int_0^\infty\frac{h^2x^2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{h^2x^2}{36}}}{\sinh x}dx=O(h^2)$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you for the reply.  Yes, you did propose a contour but did you show that the integrals along $x=\pm R$ tend to $0$ as $R\to \infty$.  It should be straightforward and your showing this would enhance this answer significantly.

Answer (score 3):

Jordan's lemma is not applicable, but under the assumption that $\omega <0$, the integral does vanish on the semicircle (or more obviously on the 3 sides of the rectangle) as $N \to \infty$.

This is because the magnitude of $e^{-i \omega z}$ decays exponentially fast to zero as $\Im(z) \to +\infty$, while the magnitude of $\frac{1}{\sinh(z)}$ decays exponentially fast to zero as $\Re(z) \to \pm \infty$.

Therefore, the value of the integral is simply $$ \begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{xe^{-i \omega x}}{\sinh(x)} \, \mathrm dx &= 2 \pi i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \operatorname{Res}\left[ \frac{ze^{-i \omega z}}{\sinh(z)}, i n \pi\right] \\ &= 2 \pi i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{z \to i n \pi} \frac{ze^{-i \omega z}}{\cosh(z)} \\ &= 2 \pi i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{in \pi e^{\omega n \pi}}{\cos(n \pi)} \\ &= -2 \pi^{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}n e^{\omega n \pi} \\ &= 2 \pi^{2} \frac{e^{\omega \pi}}{(1+e^{\omega \pi})^{2}} \\ &= \frac{\pi^{2}}{2} \operatorname{sech}^{2} \left(\frac{\omega \pi}{2} \right). \end{align}$$

---

**EDIT**:

If it's not clear that the integral vanishes on the upper side of the rectangle, notice that on the upper side of a rectangle with vertices at $z= \pm N , \pm N  + i (N+1/2) \pi$, we have $$ \begin{align} \left| \int_{- N }^{N } \frac{\left(t+i(N+1/2) \pi \right)e^{-i \omega \left(t+i(N+1/2)\pi\right)}}{\sinh \left(t+i(N+1/2)\pi) \right)} \, \mathrm dt \right| &\le e^{\omega (N+1/2)\pi }\int_{-N}^{N} \frac{t+(N+1/2)\pi}{\cosh(t)} \, \mathrm dt  \\ &= e^{\omega (N+1/2)\pi }\int_{-N }^{N } \frac{(N+1/2)\pi}{\cosh(t)} \, \mathrm dt \\ &\ < e^{\omega (N+1/2)\pi }\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(N+1/2)\pi}{\cosh(t)} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= e^{\omega (N+1/2)\pi } (N+1/2)\pi^{2}, \end{align}$$ which goes to zero as $N \to \infty$ since $\omega < 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=(N+1/2)\pi$, $N\in \mathbb{N}$. Then, on the circle $|z|=a$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{z}{\sinh(z)}\right|&=\frac a{\sqrt{\sinh^2(a\cos(\phi))\cos^2(a\sin(\phi))+\cosh^2(a\cos(\phi))\sin^2(a\sin(\phi))}}\\\\
&=\frac a{\sqrt{\sinh^2(a\cos(\phi))+\sin^2(a\sin(\phi))}}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the integral over the semi-circles $|z|=a$, in the upper and  lower half planes can be written

$$\begin{align}
I&=2\int_0^{-\pi\text{sgn}(\omega)} \frac{ae^{i\phi}e^{-i\omega ae^{i\phi}}}{e^{ae^{i\phi}}-e^{-ae^{i\phi}}} \,iae^{i\phi}\,d\phi
\end{align}$$

We have the estimate

$$\begin{align}
|I|&\le 2\int_0^{\pi} \frac{a^2 e^{-|\omega| a\sin(\phi)}}{\left|e^{ae^{i\phi}}-e^{-ae^{i\phi}}\right|} \,d\phi\\\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{a^2 e^{-|\omega| a\sin(\phi)}}{\sqrt{\sinh^2(a\cos(\phi))+\sin^2(a\sin(\phi))}}\,d\phi
\end{align}$$

Note that bounded away from $\phi=\pi/2$, the denominator grows exponentially as $e^{a\cos(\phi)}$ and overwhelms the term $a^2$ in the numerator.  And near $\phi =\pi/2$, the exponential in the numerator decays exponentially as $e^{-|\omega| a \sin(\phi)}$.

Can you convince yourself that as $a\to\infty$ that $I\to 0$?